# Conditional expected value of a branching process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, induction, expected-value

Consider the theorem and proof presented [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC09F.png). From the $\mathbb{E}(X_{t+1})=m\mathbb{E}(X_t)$ it is easy to show that $\mathbb{E}(X_{t+1}) = m^{t+1}\mathbb{E}(X_0)$. But what still bugs me is how do we *specifically* show that the conditional expected value is what is claimed, namely $\mathbb{E}(X_{t} \mid X_0 = x) = xm^{t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the branching process starts with $x$ individuals it will evolve like $x$ i.i.d. branching processes starting with one individual. So $E(X_t|X_0=x)=xE(X_t|X_0=1)$.

Comment: Can you spoon-feed me the intermediatery steps? Why is it true that a branching process starting with $x$ individuals is the same what you described?

Comment: That is part of the definition of  a branching process. Yon can refer to Branching Processes by K.  Athreya and P. Ney for the description of how a branching process evolves. @Qwaster